# How to test that a function has been called after an event was fired?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine, dom-events, spy

There is custom event fired in the `FooView` ..

```js
// views/foo_view.js

this.trigger("something:happened");
```

The associated `FooController` binds a handler to take care of the event ...

```js
// controller/foo_controller.js

initialize: function() {
  this.fooView = new FooView();
  this.fooView.bind("something:happened", this.onSomethingHappened, this);
}

onSomethingHappened: function(event) {
  // Do something else.
}
```

To test the event handling I would write the following test for [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/):

```js
it("should do something else when something happens", function() {
  var fooController = new FooController();
  spyOn(fooController, "onSomethingHappened");
  fooController.fooView.trigger("something:happened");
  expect(fooController.onSomethingHappened).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Though, the test fails ..

```
FooView should do something else when something happens.
Expected spy onSomethingHappened to have been called.
Error: Expected spy onSomethingHappened to have been called.
    at new jasmine.ExpectationResult (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:114:32)
    at null.toHaveBeenCalled (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:1235:29)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/assets/foo_spec.js?body=true:225:47)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:1064:17)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2049:8)
    at jasmine.Spec.execute (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2376:14)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at onComplete (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2092:18)
    at jasmine.Spec.finish (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2350:5)
```

Does the test fail because the event takes longer than the expectation to excute?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you spy on a function after the function was bound to the event. When jasmine create a spy it will replace the function you spy on with another function.

So what happens here, is that the original function is bound to the event

```
this.fooView.bind("something:happened", this.onSomethingHappened, this);
```

After that, the original function is replaced by the spy, but that will not have any effect on the function you pass to the `bind` function.

The solution for that is to spy `FooController.prototype.onSomethingHappened` before you create a new instance:

```
it("should do something else when something happens", function() {
  var onSomethingHappenedSpy = spyOn(FooController.prototype, "onSomethingHappened");
  var fooController = new FooController();
  fooController.fooView.trigger("something:happened");
  expect(onSomethingHappenedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I noticed that I actually **must instantiate** the controller after creating the spy. The test does **not** work when I refer to a `fooController` created in a `beforeEach` block. Thank you!

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!